# Unidentified runtime error--Could not launch/Console

Tags: java, class, compilation, runtime, runtime-error

I am experiencing a strange error after I compile and run my program.  I believe that these are called run time errors? Is that correct?  The program compiles perfectly, all of the classes included.  When I open the compiled program, I am prompted (correctly) to enter all information and after that when the program is supposed to print out the final output I receive a pop up error message ( with a yellow exclamation point on the java coffee cup) that says " The Java Class file 'Employee10.java' could not be launched.  Check console for possible error messages. " Does anyone know why I am getting this message if the rest of the program runs correctly? Is my print statement not correct?  Below I have added all the classes just incase the error isn't necessarily in Employee10.java.  If anyone can help at all with this I would be very grateful.  I am new to Java programing and could really use the help and guidance.  Thank you very much all.

Here is Employee10

```
public class Employee10
{   
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Begin Program");

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        Employee[] arr = new Employee[2];

        int j = 0;


        for ( int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            arr[0] = e1;

            String nameF = Input.getString("Please enter a First Name");
            String nameL = Input.getString("Please enter a Last Name");
            int Number = Input.getInt("Please enter an Employee Number");
            String Street = Input.getString("Please enter a Street address");
            String City = Input.getString("Please enter a City");
            String State = Input.getString("Please enter a State");
            double Zip = Input.getDouble("Please enter a Zip Code"); 
            int Month = Input.getInt("Please enter a Month in numbers");
            int Day = Input.getInt("Please enter a Day");
            int Year = Input.getInt("Please enter a Year");

            e1.setNumber(Number);
            e1.setName( new Name(nameF, nameL));
            e1.setAddress(new Address(Street, City, State, Zip));
            e1.setHireDate(new Date(Month, Day, Year));

            System.out.println(e1.getEmployeeString());


            arr[i] = e1;

        }   

        for ( j=0; j < arr.length; j++ )
        {
            System.out.println( arr[j].getEmployeeString() );
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is Employee

```
public class Employee
{
     private int Number;
     Name name;
     Address address;
     Date HireDate;

    public void setNumber ( int N )
    {
        Number = N;
    }

    public void setName ( Name n )
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setAddress ( Address a )
    {
        address = a;
    }

    public void setHireDate ( Date h )
    {
        HireDate = h;
    }

        public String getEmployeeString()
    {
        return name.getNameString() + Number + address + HireDate;
    }


}
```

Here is Date

```
public class Date
{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  public Date() { month = 0; day = 0; year = 0; }

  public void setDate( int m, int d, int y )
  {
    month = m; day = d; year = y;
  }

  public String getDateString()
  {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  public Date( int m, int d, int y )
  {
  month = m;
  day = d;
  year = y;
  }

}
```

Here is Name

```
public class Name
{
private String NameF;
private String NameL;


public void setNameF ( String F )
{
    NameF = F;
}

public void setNameL ( String L )
{
    NameL = L;
}

public String getNameString ()
{
    return NameF + NameL;

}

public Name ( String F, String L )
{
    NameF = F;
    NameL = L;
}

public Name ()
{
    NameF = "John";
    NameL = "Doe";
}
}
```

Here is Address

```
public class Address
{
private String Street;
private String City;
private String State;
private double Zip;

public void setStreet ( String s )
{
    Street = s;
}

public void setCity ( String c )
{
    City = c;
}

public void setState ( String T )
{
    State = T;
}

public void setZip ( double z )
{
    Zip = z;
}

public String GetAddressString ()
{
    return Street + City + State + Zip;
}

public Address ( String s, String c, String T, double z )
{
    Street = s;
    City = c;
    State = T;
    Zip = z;
}

public Address ()
{
    Street = "No street";
    City = " No City";
    State = "No state";
    Zip = 00000;
}
}
```

Here is Input

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class Input
{
public static byte getByte( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Byte.parseByte( input );
}

public static short getShort( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Short.parseShort( input );
}

public static int getInt( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Integer.parseInt( input );
}

public static long getLong( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Long.parseLong( input );
}

public static float getFloat( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Float.parseFloat( input );
}

public static double getDouble( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Double.parseDouble( input );
}

public static boolean getBoolean( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return Boolean.parseBoolean( input );
}

public static char getChar( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return input.charAt(0);
}

public static String getString( String s )
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
    return input;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In  Employee class file can you replace

```
public String getEmployeeString()
    {
        return name.getNameString() + Number + address + HireDate;
    }
```

with

```
public String getEmployeeString()
    {
        return name.getNameString() + Number + address.GetAddressString()  + HireDate.getDateString();
    }
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help.  What exactly should this do to fix the problem?

Comment: It is working fine for me... Could you please share the environment details like IDE, JDK, versions, project details etc

Comment: I am using an up to date mac and have used BlueJ to write and compile the program.  Then a new file appears (a .class file) for each of the 6 files I posted above.  I then click on and launch the Employee10.class file and input all the information but then it just doesn't get printed.  Is this an issue just with my computer?

Comment: @Skier1999 I tried it on Windows, STS IDE and JDK 1.8. This could be environment issue. I don't have much idea on BlueJ. I hope you are running your class file like this http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/02/BlueJ/BlueJ2.html

Comment: I tried downloading Eclipse (a different IDE) and it works! Must just be something with BlueJ or my computer... Thanks SO MUCH for all the help!

Comment: STS (which I use) is built on top of Eclipse. Anyway, great that it worked :)